# Make a histogram for one row with specific columns only

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

I'm new to R and coding in general and would really appreciate some help.

Say I have a dataframe, `df1`, with deveral columns. The important column is called `Col1`, the rest don't matter. This column contains only two classes: `Yes` or `No`

Something like this:

```
           Col1
person1     Yes
person2     Yes
person3     No
person4     Yes
person5     No
```

Another dataframe, df2, has those same samples in the columns, and genes in the rows. Something like this:

```
          person1    person2    person3     person4    person5
GeneA        23         20         2           3         200
GeneB        9          50         11          17        177
GeneC        80         0          0           445       59
GeneD        43         39         38           0         1 
GeneE        67         74         512         102       479
```

I want to make two histograms for each gene. One histogram would be only according to the samples with the label `Yes` in `df1`, and the second histogram would be for the same gene, but only for the samples that have the label `No` in `df1`. If it's possible, it would be even better if the two histograms were in the same plot, but with different colors, that would be clearer and easier to look at, to distinguish the difference between the two groups, in each gene.

How can I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps `library(dplyr);library(tidyr);library(ggplot2); df2 %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% left_join(df1 %>% rownames_to_column('name')) %>% ggplot(aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ rn + Col1, scales = "free")`

Comment: Or could be `df2 %>% rownames_to_column('rn') %>% pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% left_join(df1 %>% rownames_to_column('name')) %>% ggplot(aes(x = Col1, y = value, fill = Col1)) + geom_col() + facet_wrap(~ rn, scales = "free")`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column()
df2 %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  full_join(df1, by=c("name"="rowname")) %>% 
  mutate(Col1 = fct_reorder(Col1, value)) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value, color = Col1, fill = Col1))+
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, binwidth = 5) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
  scale_color_viridis(discrete=TRUE) +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    panel.spacing = unit(0.1, "lines"),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8)
  ) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Assigned Probability (%)") +
  facet_grid(rowname~Col1)
```

[image]

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(rowname = c("person1", "person2", "person3", "person4", 
"person5"), Col1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")


df2 <- structure(list(person1 = c(23L, 9L, 80L, 43L, 67L), person2 = c(20L, 
50L, 0L, 39L, 74L), person3 = c(2L, 11L, 0L, 38L, 512L), person4 = c(3L, 
17L, 445L, 0L, 102L), person5 = c(200L, 177L, 59L, 1L, 479L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("GeneA", 
"GeneB", "GeneC", "GeneD", "GeneE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df2 %>%
   rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>% 
  left_join(df1 %>% 
       rownames_to_column('name')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Col1, y = value, fill = Col1)) +
      geom_col() + 
      facet_wrap(~ rn, scales = "free")
```